# The CSS file won't stop modifying the HTML, even though it's been erased (Visual Studio)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I was practicing HTML and CSS, when I realised I messed up the code and couldn't figure how to solve it, so I deleted the file to start all over. But the deleted CSS file still affects my HTML.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XXLa.png),
[How the CSS still affects the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXZpD.png)

I already tried:

- Saving the project as it's modified without the CSS.
- Making a copy of the existing HTML file.
- Closing and opening the programme.

I tried looking up for why it happens but I just can't find a solution anywhere, as it's even hard for me to explain what happened.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't post pictures of code - see [why can't I upload pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  Have you tried a hard refresh (ctrl +f5)?  Browsers cache the files and won't reload them unless you do a hard refresh to request them again

Comment: You should try to remove the navigation cache, try a hard reload with (Ctrl+Shift+R)

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome:
Step 1: Open the developper tool (Ctrl+Shift+I)
Step 2: Right click the reload button.
Step 3: Click "Empty cache and hard reload" to make sure to clear the cache.